# Not able to run virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, permissions, virtualbox, 13.04, 18.04

```
VirtualBox: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: 
 dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: libQt5Core.so.5:
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Reinstall Virtualbox.

Comment: i have reinstalled virtualbox many times but the same error is coming, for uninstalling i used sudo apt remove virtualbox and sudo apt purge virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the following ubuntu package:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a
```

It seems to be missing.

Comment: supR3HardendMainGetTrustedMain: dlopen ("/usr/lib//virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: libdouble-conversion.so.1: cannot open shared object file : no such file or directory

Comment: Second error after installing everything again

Comment: QT FATAL: This application failed to start because  it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "", Available platform plugins are : eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offcreen, vnc, xcb.

Comment: @ckm: What do you mean by QT FATAL, is this a new error message while invoking Virtualbox? Maybe try to install **sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb1**. Seems your x11 is a little bit messy.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb1
[sudo] password for cmk: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libx11-xcb1 is already the newest version (2:1.6.4-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

Comment: Hold on: "8 not upgraded?" Fix that first.

Comment: what is 8 not upgraded ?

Comment: you should upgrade your system before you install a new package. this can be done easily by `sudo apt-get update` to update the apt-list, followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`. This will install the newest version of your programs, etc. listed in your apt. 8 means there are 8 packages ready to upgrade.